# Calculus 1: Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $M>0$ a constant and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a function such that $|f(x)|\geq M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Calculate the next limit: 
$$\lim_{x\to1} \dfrac{x-1}{f(x)}$$

I'm really stuck in this exercise don't know how to set the inequality to apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: should it not just be zero?

Comment: $|f(x)|\ge M$, so $\dfrac 1{|f(x)|} \le \dfrac 1 M$, and finally $\left|\dfrac{x-1}{f(x)}\right| \le \dfrac{|x-1|} M \to 0$ as $x\to1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Since $|f(x)|\geq M$,

$$0\leq \left|\frac{x-1}{f(x)}\right|\leq \left|\frac{x-1}{M}\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

since $0 \leqslant |\frac{x-1}{f(x)}| \leqslant \frac{|x-1|}{M}$ and $\frac{|x-1|}{M} \to 0$